# Use the Grep Function in a Loop in R

Tags: r

can I somehow use the grep function in a loop to search for the index variable which is incremented in a vector?

```
for (i in 1:5){
print(grep("i",d))
}
```

where d

```
d<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

The point it that in the first run of the loop grep shall search for 1, in the following for 2 ....is there some way?

Comment: You want to find the position? Or if it exists? Don't quote `"i"`, use it as a variable and probably you want `whcih()` or `match()` to find the position in the vector. i.e. `which( i == d )` or `match( i , d )` depending on requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `match`, which is vectorized so you don't need the loop.

```
x <- 1:5
set.seed(1)
d <- sample(1:10)
d
# 3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1

# find positions of (first) matches of x in d
match(x, d)
[1] 10  5  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in 1:5) print(grep(i, d))
```

Answer (score 1):

As with others, I'm not exactly sure what you're getting at/what your goals are, but what about using `Vectorize` to create a "vectorized" version of `grep`?

Here's a small reproducible example. We'll start with some sample data... a vector "d" that contains what we want to look for, and another vector "x" that contains where we want to look.

```
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
set.seed(1)
x <- paste0(letters[1:2], sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE))
x
#  [1] "a2" "b2" "a3" "b5" "a2" "b5" "a5" "b4" "a4" "b1"
```

We only need to vectorize the `"pattern"` argument to `grep`:

```
vGrep <- Vectorize(grep, vectorize.args = "pattern", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

We can now use this new function just as we would use `grep`:

```
vGrep(d, x)
# [[1]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 5
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 8 9
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 4 6 7
#
vGrep(d, x, value = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "b1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a2" "b2" "a2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "a3"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "b4" "a4"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "b5" "b5" "a5"
#
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange question, but yes you can:

```
d<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
for (i in 1:5) { print(grep(get("i"),d)) }
```

if you are looking to find some match between arbitrary ranges there are better ways to do this:

```
d = sample(1:20,5)
which(d %in% 1:5)
match(d,1:5)
any(d %in% 1:5, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Why would you use `get( "i" )` in this situation? I'm curious if you have a reason?

Comment: There is no reason to use get("i") with the data provided in the question. It is there in case the question was meant as a request to grep based on the name of a variable instead of the value.